# How to get credential information of object storage through Softlayer API?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

How can I get credential information that includes public host, private host, username, and password of the ordered object storage?

Softlayer control site uses the api below to get the information.

```
POST https://control.softlayer.com/storage/objectstorage/getclusterinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

This request may help you:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,serviceResource[name,datacenter,frontendIpAddress,backendIpAddress]]
Method: GET
```

The result will display something like this:

```
{
"id": 4309678
"username": "SLOS112233-11"
"serviceResource": {
"backendIpAddress": "https://dal05.objectstorage.service.networklayer.com/auth/v1.0/"
"frontendIpAddress": "https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/"
"name": "OBJECT_STORAGE_DAL05"
"datacenter": {
"id": 123456
"longName": "Dallas 5"
"name": "dal05"
"statusId": 2
}-
}-
}
```

If you want got information of a specific item, please apply a filter:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage?objectFilter={   "hubNetworkStorage": {     "username": {       "operation": "SLOS334455-10"     }   } }
Method: GET
```

**Some references can help you:**

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage
>   https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/Object-Storage-CDN/Set-Time-Live-TTL
>   https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/Managing-SoftLayer-Object-Storage-Through-REST-APIs